# How can I plot a raster file with its scale bar in Python?

Tags: python, raster, plot

Suppose I have a file `file.tif`. I want to plot a scale bar based on its CRS, using Python.

I've tried using a mix of `rasterio`, `matplotlib` and other techniques, but I fail because of the scale bar part, where I can't find a method that makes use of its CRS:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rasterio as rio

raster = rio.open('./file.tif')
data = raster.read()

plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar(label='clusters', fraction=0.02)
# generating the scale bar should go here and take advantage of the `raster.crs` attribute
plt.plot()
```

[image: raster plot without a scale bar]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include a single, focused question and any code that you have attempted along with any pertinent errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [matplotlib-scalebar](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib-scalebar)

```
pip install matplotlib-scalebar
```

The key to getting the scale right is to use `rasterio.plot.plotting_extent` to set the extent that you then pass to `pyplot.imshow`.

Then you can do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_scalebar.scalebar import ScaleBar

import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6, 6))

with rasterio.open("https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/raw/main/tests/data/float.tif") as raster:
    extent = plotting_extent(raster)
    data = raster.read(1)
    plt.imshow(data, extent=extent)
    scalebar = ScaleBar(1, location="lower left")
    plt.colorbar(label='clusters', fraction=0.02, ax=ax)
    ax.add_artist(scalebar)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Another example of output of above code that uses `"https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/raw/main/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif"`:

[image]

For simpler use cases where you don't need a legend, i.e if you are plotting RGB imagery, you don't need to set the extent, just use `rasterio.plot.show` which will set it correctly for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_scalebar.scalebar import ScaleBar

import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(6, 6))

with rasterio.open("https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/raw/main/tests/data/RGB.byte.tif") as raster:
    show(raster, ax=ax)
    scalebar = ScaleBar(1, location="lower left")
    ax.add_artist(scalebar)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this exactly what I needed! Many thanks. I need one clarification on your last example: I don't need to set the extent explicitly because `rasterio` already calls the `plotting_extent` function during `show`? Or it does so in another way?

Comment: Correct, see edit.